# CheckBox Columns of datagridview

Tags: c#

I want to set value of checkbox column from datagridview to database using linq [how to save values of checkboxcolumn in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR0Js.jpg)

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? it's a lot easier for us to help you out than. :)

Comment: a button to save the checked value of datagridview in database

Comment: That's not what you have tried. Can you display some code? Or you haven't tried yet? :)

Comment: no i haven't tried yet, it means happend same problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use SelectionChanged event. Than inside the handler you can access SelectedRows
>    property and get data from it. Example:

```
 private void dataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.SelectedRows) 
     {
         string value1 = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
         string value2 = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
         //...
     } 
 }
```